# Running coverage.py over unit tests with mocking

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-coverage

I'm trying to run code coverage over my program's unit tests. I'm using mock in the tests, which means I have to use python3 and up. I've installed coverage.py using pip:

```
pip install coverage
```

The installation worked and coverage is working preperly. The issue is that when I'm trying to run coverage over my unit tests it runs with python2.6 and fails on import mock although my script starts with #!/usr/bin/python3:

```
coverage run ./my_tests.py
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./my_tests.py", line 9, in module

from unittest.mock import patch

ImportError: No module named mock**

Is there a way to configure coverage to run with python3? Is there a version of coverage which works with python3 by default?

Comment: The [Mock library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) can be installed in all versions of Python starting with 2.4, so you don't have to use Python 3 in order to use `mock`.

Comment: yole, while this is not an answer to my question, it solves the issue which made me use Python3 in the first place. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently have 2.6 as your default python.  Or at least, you installed the coveragepy module in the 2.6 tree, which put 'coverage' in python26/Scripts, which then runs coveragepy with 2.6.  However, the module works with both 2.x and 3.x if you explicitly run it with one or the other instead of just the default.

I happened to have 'installed' coveragepy by cloning it in my `dev` directory.  I also wrote a cover.bat for my particular need, which is to test new and patched idlelib files in my python repository clone before committing them.  Here is my file.  Of particular relevance to your question are the lines that begin with `%py%`.  I set that to my repository build of 3.4, but you could just as easily point it to installed 3.4 or even make it an input.

```
@echo off
rem Usage: cover fileName [test_ suffix] # proper case required by coveragepy
rem filename without .py, 2nd parameter if test is not test_filename
setlocal
set py=34\pcbuild\python_d
set src=idlelib.%1
if "%2" EQU "" set tst=34/Lib/idlelib/idle_test/test_%1.py
if "%2" NEQ "" set tst=34/Lib/idlelib/idle_test/test_%2.py

%py% coveragepy run --pylib --source=%src% %tst%
%py% coveragepy report --show-missing
%py% coveragepy html
htmlcov\34_Lib_idlelib_%1.html
rem Above opens new report; htmlcov\index.html displays report index
```